# Cannot find service when attempting to remotely stop via Powershell / MSBuild

Tags: powershell, service, msbuild, continuous-integration, topshelf

I have a task to deploy two Windows services created using Topshelf to a test server as part of our continuous integration build process.

My MSBuild target file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Condition="'$(ConfigurationName)'=='Release'" Name="StopService">
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;.\ServiceStop.ps1&apos; } &quot;" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

This executes a Powershell script (well, a couple of lines) situated within the same folder within the project called ServiceStop.ps:

```
$service = get-service -ComputerName MyServerName -Name 'MyServiceName'

stop-service -InputObject $service -Verbose
```

**The problem**

When I queue a new build from within TFS, the script does successfully execute; however, the  `get-service` command fails to find the service in question - despite the fact that it is definitely there and running. The specific error from the build log is as follows:

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'MyServiceName' (TaskId:198)
```

When the script is run locally from my machine, the service on the remote machine is found and stopped successfully, making me think it is some sort of permissions issue.

**What I've tried**

I have very limited experience with Powershell. I read that credentials could be stored within a Powershell object like so:

```
$pw = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter password"
$pw | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -Path .\storedPassword.txt

$password = get-content .\storedPassword.txt | convertto-securestring
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "myAdminAccountName",$password
```

However, it would appear that `get-service` does not have any method to pass credentials to it.

I also experimented with using PSExec to remotely start and stop the service, but ran into similar issues.

**Some questions I reviewed**

[Using PowerShell credentials without being prompted for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password)

[Powershell stop-service error: cannot find any service with service name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917761/powershell-stop-service-error-cannot-find-any-service-with-service-name)

[Powershell Get-WmiObject Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968210/powershell-get-wmiobject-access-is-denied)

[Saving credentials for reuse by powershell and error ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109958/saving-credentials-for-reuse-by-powershell-and-error-convertto-securestring-ke)

I have spent more time on this issue than I can really afford, so would appreciate any help / guidance / comments that may help.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I was able to confirm that the Powershell script was receiving information from the MSBuild task, as the log showed Powershell output.

However, I ran out of time to find a solution and instead worked around the issue by dropping the updated services binaries onto the target server and wrote a Powershell script that installed them from there.

Thanks a lot to those that commented on the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it can help but I'd start with initial diagnostic - launch get-service without name parameter (with ComputerName only) and ensure (using manual check) that this command does actually reach your server, and isn't executed locally

Comment: Try with [SC.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599.aspx)

Comment: Or `gwmi win32_service -credential`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that nothing is being passed from the MSBuild target file to the powershell script. You are defining the name of the service involved via ' marks, so its taking that rather than what the MSBuild target file is doing.

I would suggest you find out how to pass this variable, otherwise the script won't be able to pick this up correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I shall revisit this issue later on today and advise as to the outcome.

Comment: The MSBuild target file is definitely passing parameters to Powershell. I was able to confirm this as the full command was visible within the log file. However, I ran out of time to look at this. THanks a lot for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a complete stab in the dark, but your service name needs the **TopShelf** *instance* name including when you call get-service.

For example your service might be called "MyWindowsService" but what you need to programmatically look for is "MyWindowsService$default"